# stripping singular / from a csv file

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv, stripping

I have a csv file which has a few areas where / proceeded by nothing and proceeded by nothing that I'd like to strip out.  The catch is, I also have other items in the file which have a / that I don't want to strip out.

an example:

```
/abc, /, akaksdhfaiwe
/, /foo, /bar
```

I'd like to be:

```
/abc,, akaksdhfaiwe
, /foo, /bar
```

How do I do this?  I can't use gsub('^/', '') because it would strip out the /abc /foo /bar.  And for the life of me, I can't seem to find an 'ends with'.  I was hoping that \Z would work, no luck.

Any takers?

I've been using fasterCSV for a lot of the manipulation which has been pretty great so far.

Comment: Oh, you want to stay in ruby.... (can't edit the above comment for some reason)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file isn't that big then you could slurp it into memory while cleaning it up and then write it out again:

```
clean = [ ]
CSV.open(your_csv).each { |r| csv << r.map { |e| e.sub(/^\s*\/$/, '') } }
out = CSV.open(your_csv, 'wb')
clean.each { |r| out << r }  
out.close
```

If you somehow have an incredibly massive CSV file that won't fit in memory all at once:

```
out = CSV.open('tempfile.csv', 'wb')
CSV.open(your_csv).each { |r| out << r.map { |e| e.sub(/^\s*\/$/, '') } }
out.close
File.rename('tempfile.csv', your_csv)
```

Either should turn this:

```
/abc, /, akaksdhfaiwe
/, /foo, /bar
```

into

```
/abc,"", akaksdhfaiwe
"", /foo, /bar
```

Comment: it's a MASSIVE file.  I mean, MASSIVE.  So reading into memory is a no go.  But that second one.  I will give it a go.  Thanks Mu.

Answer (score 0):

With ruby you can do:

```
"/asdf /, /fdsa".gsub("/,", ",")
```